# Azure Data Factory Configuration Causing SftpPermissionDenied Error

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have configured my ADF Copy activity with the following configuration in Sink mode

```
@concat(pipeline().parameters.TableName,'_',activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.as_of_date,'_',formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss'),'.csv')
```

[image]

However, that configuration results in the following SFTP error:
ErrorCode=SftpPermissionDenied,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Permission denied to access 'xxxxxxx_2023-05-31T00:00:00_.csv'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SftpConnector,''Type=Renci.SshNet.Common.SftpPermissionDeniedException,Message=Permission denied,Source=Renci.SshNet,'

When I configure the Sink with the following, I don't get any errors

```
@concat(
    pipeline().parameters.TableName,
    '_',
    formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMdd'),
    '_',
    formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss'), '.csv'
    )
```

The Sink connection looks like the following:

[image]

Any thoughts, as I can't think of anything that may be causing this

So, just to reiterate, the following results in ErrorCode=SftpPermissionDenied

```
@concat(
    pipeline().parameters.TableName,
    '_',
    activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.as_of_date,
    '_',
    formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss'), '.csv'
    )
```

However, the following copies to the SFTP Server without any errors:

```
@concat(
    pipeline().parameters.TableName,
    '_',
    formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMdd'),
    '_',
    formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss'), '.csv'
    )
```

They are virtually identical. So, I have no idea what is going on

ok, I think I'm getting close to the problem

When I remove the lookup activity as follows, I don't get any errors:

```
@concat(
    pipeline().parameters.TableName,
    '_',
    formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss'),'.csv'
    )
```

So, it would appear the lookup activity is causing the Error

```
ErrorCode=SftpPermissionDenied
```

The lookup activity is as follows:

[image]

Hopefully, I've provided enough information to for someone to provide a solution or at least some suggestions

One thing I have noticed is that if I remove the paramater from the Sink connection, see image I don't get the error `ErrorCode=SftpPermissionDenied` however only the raw file is copied ie.without datetime etc...

[image]

OK, just tested again with the parameter for the 'File name' removed. I am not getting the error, but only the raw file to sent to the STFP Server without any of the parameters as shown here:

```
@concat(
    pipeline().parameters.TableName,
    '_',
    activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.as_of_date,
    '_',
    formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss'),'.csv'
    )
```

Your thoughts most welcomed

I am truly clutching at straws here, but I think the problem could also be with ADF attempting to overwrite the existing file on the SFTP Server. I say this because with out the parameters for the File name I don't get the error however it just overwrites the existing file on the SFTP Server.

As I mentioned, I'm just clutching at straws because I'm lost for any ideas why I'm getting the error

Comment: Can you set the value for `max concurrent connection` as 1

Comment: Hi @Aswin, should I set it on ADF or the SFTP Server?

Comment: oh, sorry, I see you meant on ADF

Comment: Hi @Aswin, still getting the error ```ErrorCode=SftpPermissionDenied,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Permission denied to access 'FundManagers_2023-05-31T00:00:00_20230615124421.csv'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SftpConnector,''Type=Renci.SshNet.Common.SftpPermissionDeniedException,Message=Permission denied,Source=Renci.SshNet,'```

Comment: Hi @Aswin, I have just updated the question, to say that when I remove the parameter from 'File Name' I don't get the error, however I only get the raw filename

Comment: Hi @Saideep and Aswin, I have updated the question to say that the problem appears only when I'm adding a parameter to the File name. Any thoughts?